# Custom domain email not working with Heroku

Tags: email, heroku, hosting

I have an app hosted on Heroku free dynos. I purchased a domain name from ewall host and added a CNAME record to point it to Heroku app as Heroku dosen't provide nameservers.

I created an email on my domain `email@mydomain.com`.

The problem is I can send email via my app but I can't receive email. My domain provider is telling me something about adding a MX record.

I tried setting email to email client but still its not working.

How can I get email working?

[image: this is the target that i copied]

[image: this is my CNAME Record]

Comment: What exactly does "I created an email on my domain `email@mydomain.com`" mean? Heroku doesn't provide mailboxes for incoming email. Your domain provider probably does (you might have to turn it on and pay a fee) but it might not. There are lots of email providers out there, paid and free, that would work just fine. Pick one and follow its setup instructions: it should give you the MX value you need to use with your registrar.

Comment: My domain registrar provides me with 2 email accounts.but i can receive email on that account because of CNAME record that heroku provided..i talked to my registrar and they told i need MX value from my hosting provider that is heroku in my case..

Comment: (Note that this likely has nothing to do with Heroku, and it may stem from a misunderstanding of how email works. Sending email from a given address like `email@mydomain.com` doesn't usually require that account to exist. You don't even need to have any association with `domain.com`, though today there are reasonably good protections in place on many mail exchangers to recognize this.)

Comment: Then ask your registrar for help. You say "My domain provider is telling me something about adding a MX record"; what _exactly_ are they saying? Please copy and paste.

Comment: i talked to them and they told for email to work i need to use default A record...and if i change A record to default them CNAME record is also modified which is pointing to the heroku app.

Comment: Unfortunately, the recommendations you're passing on here aren't very clear and don't sound like they make sense. Did they give you exact instructions, e.g. "create an A record for `some` subdomain pointing to `1.2.3.4`", or just say "use a default A record"?

Comment: they said the A record need to point to their record that is the default record...i am trying my best to be as clear as i can..let me post some screen shot if it might help..

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not sure what they're recommending. I don't understand why an A record would have any impact on mail delivery (normally we'd talk about MX records for mail). Since I don't understand what they're telling you I can't offer a solution.